# Using OpenGl.net c#. My textures are getting strange lines on them

Tags: c#, opengl

I am programming a game engine currently in opengl.net c# and I am having issues with displaying textures. From the image below you can tell that there are some strange lines on the texture that should not exist. What can I do the remedy the problem?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5H3n.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaeAj.jpg <-- Original image and the relevant code.

EDIT: I figured it out. Somehow on the windows form there was mipmapping going on when there should not have been. The MipMaping was set to one which ended up slightly AA'ing the actual texture.

Comment: Show the relevant code parts. Are you using linear interpolation or mipmaps?

Comment: Could you also add the original image vs the rendered one you have already?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/OQqeK Original image as well as the relevant code.

Comment: The rendered image has a blue background? Is that because of another sprite drawn before it?

Comment: The background has been just set to blue in openGL.

Comment: The default texture minification filter requires mipmaps. You should set texture sampler parameters after binding the texture on the active unit.